# plotly (Python) - How to draw lines of different colors in the same Scatter object

Tags: python-3.x, plotly

I’m currently making a network visualization with plotly; I started from this [tutorial](https://plot.ly/python/network-graphs/) and after a few modifications, managed to obtain my figure. The point is that I want to color the edges according to some values, but here they are all of the same color. It deals with this `Scatter` object :

```
edge_trace = go.Scatter(
    x=[],
    y=[],
    line=dict(width=0.5, color='#888'),
    hoverinfo='none',
    mode='lines')
```

I loop on my values to fill the `edge_trace['x']` and `edge_trace['y']` list of coordinates, and I tried to do the same with the `edge_trace[line]['color']` attribute instead of only specifying a single color. But it gave me an error. How can I do that ? Do I have to create a `Scatter` object for each edge of the graph ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Answer : i've been told it's not possible : it is mandatory to create a Scatter object for each line.